# Not able to get values stored in Python Django request session

Tags: python, rest, session, django-rest-framework

Hellos firends,

I have REST service in Python Django application. I am trying to store some values in the request session post successful login service call.

like the following

```
request.session['valid']=True
```

and the  I am able to check that the values set properly.

The in the next request when I am trying to retrieve the value I am not able to find any of the keys I had stored.

following is the code to retrieve the keys

```
 if 'valid' not in request.session:
    print('Invalid request. . .')
    return False
 elif request.session['valid']==True:
    username=request.session['username']
    print('Request validated. . .')
    return True
```

I have the frontend app running on React and Backend REST is on DRF. After the login is done on the following code,

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_details(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
          }


            # Assuming at this point login is successful, so I am setting the session
            request.session['username']=TF_VAR_user_name
            request=initSession(request)

            data = txt

            response = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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', headers=headers, data=data)
            print(response)
            return Response(data_json)

        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as exc:
            error, = exc.args
            m = error.message
            err="Oracle-Error-Message: "+ str(error.code) + " Oracle-Error-Message: "+error.message
            dic2={"Oracle-Error-Code":str(error.code),"Oracle-Error-Message":error.message}
            print(dic2)
            m=json.dumps(dic2)
            n=json.loads(m)
            txt="{'text':'User "+atp_userid+" Oracle-Error-Message: "+error.message+"'}"
            data = txt
            response = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/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', headers=headers, data=data)
            return Response(n)

    else:
        return Response({ "message":"Unauthoried, please login."},status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

The I am trying to read Stored values in the following code,

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def dashboard(request):
        if 'valid' not in request.session:
        print('Invalid request. . .')
     elif request.session['valid']==True:
        username=request.session['username']
        print('Request validated. . .')
```

Please help me how can store values in session and retrieve in the subsequent request. I am sorry for the trouble as I am completely new to Python and Django

Comment: Sessions relies on the session cookie. If your client doesn't send it back (which implies you sent it first) then of course you won't have your session data.

Comment: Which DRF Authentication classes are you using on this view?

Comment: My frontend is in React and it is consuming REST services written in Django. Following is the content of the middleware settings

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
  ]